# What is this plant growing by the road?

Tags: identification

It is growing by itself. Obviously very competitive.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Aleksandar M! With identification questions, we have a few important guidelines, so you can get the best answers. We always need the location, so please add that to all of your questions. The guidelines are here, https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info. Please take them into account, as they apply to everyone. Your plants are lovely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a beautiful plant.  I believe it is Purple Loosestrife.  The top dog at the top of the most invasive plant of all in the States.  Lythrum salicaria.  Each flower produces like a zillion seeds.  Loves the wetlands but can withstand the sides of hot asphalt roads and gravel.

Beautiful but is causing much death of indigenous species and ecosystems it was never meant to inhabit.  It got over here because someone thought it beautiful and brought it over here.

See the leaves?  Arranged in pairs and severely offset by 90 degrees from the lower node of leaves.  Fairly distinctive.

Where is it you live?  If I am correct, I am not very correct IDing from pictures, someone else will surely check my answer, but if this is correct someone should call the Weed Cops and squeal loudly.  Those beautiful flowers should be weed wacked right down before they are able to produce seed.  And done every year until they don't exist anymore in that area.  Starve them out.

Herbicides can't be used shouldn't be used in our wet lands, on the sides of roads where they will be leached everywhere else.  There are weed cops (2 per state)? that will work with the owners and/or city/county/municipalities to try to eradicate.  This is sort of like calling 911 for help.  Cooperative Extension Service would be the first one I'd call.  The Weed Cops work under their umbrella, not the city or county normally.

Please let us know what you learn?

[Purple Loosestrife](https://www.dnr.state.mn.us/invasives/aquaticplants/purpleloosestrife/index.html)

Comment: It is illegal to plant it in many states because it is so invasive.

Comment: It is 200 yards from my yard. Is my yard in danger of being infested?

Comment: Of course your yard if anything already has seeds of this plant in the soil!  Weeds are just not the monsters people make them out to be.  I have never had a worry about weeds and I did commercial landscape maintenance for hundreds and hundreds of other's yards.

Comment: They key is a hula hoe, a hoe with a hole in the middle of a sharpened metal band or a weed wacker in the hands of a professional...simply knocking down baby plants while they are newly germinated.  Never allow any weed to flower.  I smother weeds with this human poo mulch without weed seeds or pesticide residues...gorgeous mulch for landscapes.  Weeds?  If you left for a vacation of 3 months, yeah, you would find these plants loving your yard.  Contact the weed cops seriously, not a pesticide company!  They will love you for pointing this out...if it is Loosestrife.

Comment: @blacksmith37 This may be illegal in many states if not all states but check out the nurseries next time you visit.  They sell this very plant in all the nurseries I've been in, worked in, worked with.  Amazing.  This is the nightmare invasive plant of all.